# Android send 1 data from activity1 to activity2 TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I need help with sending data from 1 activity to another using TabHost.

Normally, with a button click to switch tabs + activity I used this code:

```
MainActivity tabs = (MainActivity) getParent();
tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);//swwitch tabs  //this selects tab2 on click
```

This is what I'm trying to do but it crashes:

Activity1

```
 Intent i = getParent().getIntent();
                i.putExtra(contactId, "a");
                i.putExtra("tab", 1);
                MainActivity tabs = (MainActivity) getParent();
                tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

Activity2

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twoo);
        Intent i = getParent().getIntent();
        int a = i.getIntExtra("a", 0);
        int sum = a ;
        Toast.makeText(twoo.this, sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I'm aware of this code to send data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent)
```

but this isn't what I'm looking for as this code opens the entire activity form removing the tabs.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @a ron, Have you solved your question or shall I update my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used tabs before, but how about saving your data to shared preferences and then getting it back out after changing tabs?

```
//in
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("AppData",MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.edit().putString("Email",EmailEditText.getText().toString()).apply();

//out
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("AppData",MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = pref.getString("Email","");
```

Answer (score 0):

> now this is what am trying to do but it crashes

I think you misstyped the `putExtra()` you have to put on the first parameter the "reference" that you want to use for take the value on the second `Activity` and on the second value **must** be, the value that you want to pass.

```
Intent i = getParent().getIntent();
i.putExtra(contactId, "a"); <------- Try to change it to i.putExtra("a", contactId);
i.putExtra("tab", 1);
MainActivity tabs = (MainActivity) getParent();
tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

Read this [Intent putExtra(String string, Bundle bundle) Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) for more information.